# icCube - removing date range through a Perspective

Tags: mdx, iccube

I would like to build a Perspective, where all days older than 3 months are removed. In MDX the following would work:

```
filter([date].[date].[day].members, [date].[date].CurrentMember.properties('KEY',TYPED) <= today()->minusMonths(3))
```

But in the Perspective the function minusMonth() is apparently not known:

```
Perspective 'Perspective1 ': operator '>' syntax error (left-operand:'date' (right-operand:'empty')
```

Is there a different way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message has been improved/fixed. Actually the error is because a date member has no key (e.g., the optional member used to map unresolved rows) and then

```
null <= today()
```

is generating the error. To fix it, you need to check first for that member in the filtering expression.

Hope that helps.